# Join rest of string array

Tags: c#, join, substring, arrays

```
private static string SetValue(string input, string reference)
{
    string[] sentence = input.Split(' ');
    for(int word = 0; word<sentence.Length; word++)
    {
        if (sentence[word].Equals(reference, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return String.Join(" ", sentence.subarray(word+1,sentence.Length))
        }
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish `sentence.subarray(word+1,sentence.Length)` easily or do this in another way?

Comment: Take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.Join` has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0.aspx) specifically for this:

```
return String.Join(" ", sentence, word + 1, sentence.Length - (word + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are strictly looking for a Subarray solution independent of the string.Join() function, and you are using a version of .NET with Linq support, then may I recommend:

```
sentence.Skip(word + 1);
```

Comment: My original answer included a ToArray() call at the end since a .NET version of subarray was requested.

Comment: Just go ahead and edit it back, and hopefully no-one else will "correct" it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an overload [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) with `index`:

```
return string.Join(" ", sentence.Where((w, i) => i > word));
```

Comment: Don't do this. `X.Where((x, i) => i > I)` gives the same results as `X.Skip(I + 1)` but is marginally less efficient and takes longer to figure out.

Comment: @Rawling: that's true, just another approach, but don't fall down much on *pre-mature optimization*, I like the approach using `SKip(word + 1)`, it's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `SkipWhile` instead of your for loop.

```
private static string SetValue(string input, string reference)
{
    var sentence = input.Split(" ");
    // Skip up to the reference (but not the reference itself)
    var rest = sentence.SkipWhile( 
        s => !s.Equals(reference, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    rest = rest.Skip(1); // Skip the reference
    return string.Join(" ", rest);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't SkipWhile include the item for which the predicate is true?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure Enumerable has `Join`. You might need to add `ToArray` after `Skip(1)`.

Comment: IEnumerable<string> has a [Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx), but it's not [the Join Method you mean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx). However, the String.Join Method has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) that takes an IEnumerable<string>.

Comment: And now you need to add a few semicolons and variable declarations to make it actually compile :-)

Comment: Right. Too much Ruby lately ^^'.